# Error message setting up Browser Stack with cypress: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserstack-cypress-cli'

Tags: automation, automated-tests, cypress, browserstack

I am trying to install browserStac using he following command:

```
npm install -g browserstack-cypress-cli
```

I Got the following error message:

```
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserstack-cypress-cli
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserstack-cypress-cli'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserstack-cypress-cli'] {
➜  RHS.Website.Automation git:(regression)                                       
npm install -g browserstack-cypress-cli

npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserstack-cypress-cli
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserstack-cypress-cli'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserstack-cypress-cli'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserstack-cypress-cli'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/jacquelinegeorge/.npm/_logs/2022-12-13T12_31_56_083Z-debug-0.log
➜  RHS.Website.Automation git:(regression)
```

I'm honestly very confused right because this should this framework is new and I've attempted to install cypress before.

What is wrong exactly and and how do I fix it.

Comment: Try with sudo access.

Comment: So would I be correct in saying this should be `sudo npm install -g browserstack-cypress-cli` @AshwaniPathak

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a permission issue.
You should be using:

```
sudo npm install -g browserstack-cypress-cli
```